# Extract subset of methods from WSDL

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, gsoap

I'm integrating with a web service providing a huge WSDL file containing lots of methods. Of those methods, I only need a few (up to 10) plus (obviously) corresponding types used in them. Is there a way (except manually editing the WSDL file) to extract only a subset of methods and create new WSDL file for the very same web service? Maybe there is a tool or a script of some kind in existance? I failed finding one myself.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm using gSOAP-provided `wsdl2h` and `soapcpp2` utilities to convert aforementioned WSDL file into C++ wrapper, and then compile it into static library. The size of the library then comes out around 300-500 MB depending on compiler and type of build (debug or release), that is if I even succeed compiling it, which obviously is too much for a simple integration I'm implementing, and sometimes even too much for compiler to then link the library with an executable.

gSOAP-specific solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

That is one huge WSDL. I would suggest that you get yourself a copy of either Liquid XML designer or Altova XML spy. These tools will make editing the WSDL much easier. I don't know of any scripts that will automate this for you.

It would be a simple matter of visually deleting the operations you don't need in the WSDL if you use either one of the two tools mentioned above.

I have used both these tools for editing WSDL's and they make the job trivial.